# How to remove everything after last "/" in SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL SERVER column named `full_url` of type `nvarchar(1000)`. Sample string look like a classic web url:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/somemorefolder/document.txt
```

What i need is, that i can execute a SQL Statement, **which removes the last "/" and everything after this char**, so that the result looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/somemorefolder
```

I found a solution for MySQL but this does not work for SQL Server:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1)) FROM path)
FROM   my_table;
```

I have also tried this SQL Statement, but this also didnt work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([full_url ], len([full_url ]) - charindex('/', reverse([full_url ]))) from myTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CHARINDEX()` trick, with the help of `REVERSE()`, can work with some modification:

```sql
SELECT
    full_url,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(full_url),
                      CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(full_url)) + 1,
                      LEN(full_url))
    ) AS partial_url
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using the same functions as used by Tim:

```
SELECT 
    full_url,
    SUBSTRING(full_url,
              1,
              (LEN(full_url) - CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(full_url)))
    ) AS partial_url
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This answer is probably preferable to mine, as it only calls `REVERSE()` once +1.